Excel slicer condition
I have the following current situation:
There is a source table that includes a column for times, counters, groups, and teams, among others. From this table, I created a pivot table, from which I then generated a chart where the times are sorted in ascending order by the counters as bars. I also created two slicers from this pivot table, which filter by group and team and update the chart accordingly.
Now, I want to display the averages of the times as lines in this chart. For this, I created three columns in the source table: overall average (calculates the average over all times), group average (calculates the average of the respective team times), and team average.
My goal is for the averages to change dynamically based on the slicer selection. If no selection is made, the time bars and the overall average should be displayed. However, if I select a team in the team slicer, this slicer should display not only the time bars for the team but also the averages for this team and not the overall averages.
Is there a solution for this, perhaps a helper column that says: if both slicers are off -> overall average, if group slicer is on -> switch from overall average to group average, etc.?

All data in the same chart

I would have one cell to select the slicer eg team and then use averageif() or averageifs()  to calculate the average. Without any copiable data to base an example on you can look at the Excel examples for those functions.
